# Ajax output to second div using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a new user of ajax; so...

I am using ajax on a simple html page to access a php script to receive data, calculate results using data in an mysql table, and echo results in a div on the same page. My javascript statement to do this is:

```
$.post('ajax/phpscript.php', {
        postuser:theuser,
        postname:uans1
    }, function(data) {
        $('#outputdiv1').html(data);
    }
);
```

The php echo output goes to a div on the main page called outputdiv1.

I got that part; no problem. Not sure exactly how it works, but it does work.

I would also like to echo output to a different div (which I will call outputdiv2) on the same page, using the php script. In my php script, How do I refer to or echo output this other div?

I guess I could have a second $.post statement in the javascript code, accessing a second php script. But that would force me to access the mysql database a second time. Doesn't seem efficient to me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

HTML code is here:

theuser is defined earlier

```
<table width=400 align=center><tr><td>
There is a question here, with 2 possible answers:<p>
<form>
<input type=radio style="width:22px; height:22px" name="ques1" id="opt1" value="answer 1" onclick="post1()">&nbsp; answer 1<br>
<input type=radio style="width:22px; height:22px" name="ques1" id="opt2" value="answer 2" onclick="post1()">&nbsp; answer 2<br>

</form>
<div id="outdiv1">first response from php will go here, beneath the question.<br></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function post1() {
    var uans1 = "none"
    if (document.getElementById("opt2").checked)   {
        uans1 = "answer 2"
    }
    if (document.getElementById("opt1").checked)   {
        uans1 = "answer 1"
    }
    $.post('ajax/phpscript.php',{postuser:theuser,postname:uans1}, function(data) {$('#ans1div').html(data);});
}
</script>


</td>
<td width=20%>
<div id="outputdiv2">
second response from php will go here, to the right of the question.<p>
</div>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

first response will not be the same as the second response.

Comment: Can you add your html structure in your question?

Comment: You want to put same response to other div?

Comment: No, I want a different response in the second div.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSON to communicate and return an array. something like this in js

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/phpscript.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        postuser: theuser,
        postname: uans1
    },
    dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function(data) {
    if ($.isArray(data)) {
        $('#outputdiv1').html(data[0]);
        $('#outputdiv2').html(data[1]);
    }
});
```

And your php script should do something look like this

```
<?php
    include('dbconnection.php');
    $result = [];
    //SELECT data for div1 (part you already have)
    $result[] = $mysql_result_as_html_for_outputdiv_1; // In your case this would be a html string
    //SELECT other data for div2
    $result[] = $mysql_result_as_html_for_outputdiv_2; // In your case this would be a html string

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

An even more clean solution would be to just return the data as objects from php  and make some templates in js suitable for your data.

Comment: Thanks; is that all the code I need? I have not used json.

Comment: For the simple solution (array of html strings) the js code is complete

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand this: who write in the div is javascript, not php, cause you are using ajax. Ajax is a way to comunicate with php, and give a response. Now you need to handle this response with javascript.

If you want to put the same content in outputdiv1 and outputdiv2, you not need to post ajax again, only write it in two divs.

```
$.post('ajax/phpscript.php',{postuser:theuser,postname:uans1}, function(data) {$('#outputdiv1').html(data);$('#outputdiv2').html(data);});
```

if you want different data i suggest you think the system to get all result that you need in one post request and return it in a json format (see http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php), so you can handle better with JSON.parse() in client side.